# Energy Sword Smoke Effect

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, volumetrics

I am trying to recreate Ekkos sword from League of Legends. I've got most of the modeling done but I am completely stumped on making a blade that looks good. I've tried smoke sims and volumetric emissions. Open to any ideas.
I've attached my work(first) and the blades I am trying to recreate after.
Open to any help.
[image: My work]
[image: End Result]
[image: End Result]

Comment: That is a pretty good looking sword. So I have seen the reference image you have given and the only problem I see is with the texturing, also, a little bit of modeling. I would say to use a different texture. The texture from the image is emerald-cyan or something like that, but your rendered sword is having more of a sky blue texture. I will recommend this texture I found :[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQN6U.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQN6U.jpg) For a much better effect. Use the emission section in principled bsdf and set it to something like 0.345 and the co

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my take on it. Of course you could tweak the colors a little so that they look better. I've used a 4D Voronoi Texture for the main structure, this way you can animate the W value to have some floating energy effect.

[image]

Comment: thanks so much for the help. I never would have thought of that

Answer (score 8):

You could try giving it a material like this:

[image: Glow1]

The first thing I did was warp the object vector using a Noise Texture to help give the rest a bit more of a "swirly/smoky" look. Next, I used this as the input vector for another Noise Texture (to make it extra distorted) and ran the result through a colored ColorRamp.

[image: Glow2]

For the "energy bolts", I used the same warped vector as the input for a Voronoi Texture set to *Distance To Edge*. I inverted the result and clamped it with a ColorRamp to make the "Lightning" stand out I then mixed this with the colors using a MixRGB node set to *lighten* to have good control over how much lightning is added (too bright looks fake):

[image: Glow3]

If you want to soften the effect overall (looks even less fake), you can mix the final result with fitting, solid color. Finally, I suggest running the result through an Emission Shader with the strength turned up a bit. Don't forget to enable Bloom to make it glow:

[image: Glow4]

Comment: thanks so much for the detailed explanation. Really made me rethink what I know about the node system